A more symmetric orthogonalization procedure for three vectors?
If $(v_1,v_2)$ are two non-zero linearly independent unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it follows that
$$ e_1 = \frac{v_1 + v_2}{\sqrt{2 (1 + \left< v_1,v_2\right>)}}, \ e_2 = \frac{v_1 - v_2}{\sqrt{2 (1 - \left< v_1,v_2 \right>)}}$$
forms an orthonormal basis of a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If we use the Gram-Schmidt proceudre for the same vectors, we have
$$ e_1' = v_1, e_2' = \frac{v_2 - \left< v_1, v_2 \right> v_1}{\sqrt{1 - \left< v_1,v_2\right>^2}} ,$$
in which we have chosen $v_1$ to be the "priviledged" vector.
The first orthonormalization is more symmetric with respect to $(v_1,v_2)$ than the Gram-Schmidt procedure, and I am wondering if there is a "easy" way to generalize this type of orthogonalization for three vectors $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$? To begin the procedure, one might consider a matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1' \\ v_2' \\ v_3' \end{pmatrix} , $$
then we should choose the coefficients of the matrix such that $\left< v_i', v_j' \right> = \delta_{ij}$. Is there a simple way to "guess" the coefficients that would satisfy this property, in the same way as for the $(v_1,v_2)$ example?

It's hard to say what makes a basis more "symmetric". One way to think about this is: if you start with an orthonormal basis $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ then for any orthogonal transformation $A$ (that is, $A^{-1} = A^T$), the ordered tuple $(Av_1, Av_2, Av_3)$ will be another orthonormal basis. You can now ask for extra properties for the matrix $A$.

Your symbolic matrix equation
$$
M\pmatrix{v_1\v_2\v_3} = \pmatrix{v_1'\v_2'\v_3'},
$$
where $M$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and the $v_i$ and $v_i'$ are vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, can be written as the straightforward matrix equation
$$
\pmatrix{v_1 & v_2 & v_3}M^T = \pmatrix{v_1' & v_2' & v_3'}.
$$

We can think of your first formula as the outcome of a two-step procedure. First, obtain an alternative basis of $\text{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ in which each vector of the basis contains "equal parts" of $v_1$ and $v_2$, so that neither $v_1$ nor $v_2$ is "privileged" in the Gram Schmidt process that follows. In this case, we can take $w_1 = v_1 + v_2$ and $w_2 = v_1 - v_2$. Applying the Gram-Schmidt process to $(w_1,w_2)$ then produces your basis $(e_1,e_2)$.
There is an additional "niceness" to this transformation in that, besides the formulas for the $w_i$ giving equal "weight" to each $v_i$, the associated matrix $M$ for which
$$
\pmatrix{v_1 & v_2}M = \pmatrix{w_1 & w_2}
$$
is orthogonal (rather, it becomes orthogonal if we scale the $w_i$ down by $\sqrt{2}$).
With that in mind: if you allow for the use of complex numbers, one seemingly natural generalization is to take
$$
\pmatrix{v_1' & v_2' & \cdots & v_n'} = \pmatrix{w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_n}W, 
$$
where $W$ denotes a DFT matrix. Note that $W$ is unitary, which is to say that $W^*W = I$, where $W^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $W$. So for $n = 3$, this would mean that we take
$$
w_1 = v_1 + v_2 + v_3\\
w_2 = v_1 + \omega v_2 + \omega^2 v_3\\
w_3 = v_1 + \omega^2 v_2 + \omega v_3,
$$
where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3} = -\frac 12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$.
Note that for the purposes of Gram Schmidt, we should use the sesquilinear "dot-product".
